# No data since domain/https change on Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, https, google-analytics, dns, analytics

I'm absolutely stumped. I've always had GA set up on my blog and it's always worked.

I recently moved, first from http://helloarchie.blue to http://helloarchie.co, and then to https://helloarchie.co.

It hasn't worked since the initial domain change.

I've checked with tag assistant and the code is there with no errors, but still no data is pulling through.

Both URLs in the settings correct and have been for about 4/5 days now. I haven't amended my original view and I've set up a new view with no filters (around 4/5 days ago) yet nothing is coming through on either of them.

I'm speaking to someone in the Google Communities but she hasn't been of much help so I'm exhausting every avenue because I can not figure this out!

Comment: I don't think you'll get much more help here - looking at the debugger the call is going out fine, and if you are sure that this is the correct account id then the problem must be at the receiving end.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the domain and it seems that you are sending the tracking event to google (I see a call to "https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&_v=j60&a=1188272812&t=pageview&_s=1&dl=https%3A%2F%2Fhelloarchie.co.....")

I would suggest checking if you have any filters configured excluding anything but the old domain or something of the sort:

[image: Settings->View->Filters]

Search if you have an "include only from hostname" :

[image: Filter]